# Python Generator call counter not increasing unless yield is called

Tags: python, python-2.7, generator, yield

I am using the `scandir` library to look over all files on my computer. I would like to stop the loop once I've checked 100 records. If the `yield` statement is never called, my variable, `c` never increases and the loop doesn't stop. I've put in some bogus file name `thisfilewontbefound` that will never be found thus `yield` is never reached. Why is `c` not incrementing?

```
from scandir import scandir, walk
import sys

def subdirs(path):
    for path, folders, files in walk(path):
        for files in scandir(path):
            if 'thisfilewontbefound' in files.path:
                yield files.path

c = 0
for i in subdirs('C:\\'):
    if c > 100:
        print "test over"
        sys.exit()
    c += 1
    print i
```

Comment: Because `subdirs` never yields, the body of `for i in subdirs(...)` never runs.

Comment: @gill shouldn't it still interate for each folder in C:\?

Comment: @user2242044 the first iteration of subdirs will never yield any elements if the file does not exist.

Comment: `subdirs` will still iterate but without `yield`-ing anything to iterate through for the `for` loop, so at the end `for` loop never runs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `for` loop is waiting for the generator. The generator will *only* produce a value if `yield` is executed. But `yield` is never executed because there is no such file, so the `for` loop will wait a long time, until *all* files on your `C:` drive have been scanned and the generator ends without ever yielding anything.

Either put the counter in the generator, or don't filter on files in your generator and have it yield more often.

Comment: for your second suggestion of having it yield more often, would it best best to let the generator do the filtering or the for loop in terms of efficiency?

Comment: @user2242044: without the filter, your generator is nothing more than an extra empty wrapper around the `os.walk()` generator. There is not really any point in having that generator at that point. :-)